# Convert an HTML form field to a JSON object with inner objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, forms

Given the following HTML form:

```
<form id="myform">
  Company: <input type="text" name="Company" value="ACME, INC."/>
  First Name: <input type="text" name="Contact.FirstName" value="Daffy"/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="Contact.LastName" value="Duck"/>
</form>
```

What is the best way serialize this form in javascript to a JSON object in the format:

```
{
  Company:"ACME, INC.",
  Contact:{FirstName:"Daffy", LastName:"Duck"}
}
```

Also note that there might be more than 1 "." sign in the field name.

Comment: Yes, i have done this for Spring Form's, and I did it this exact same way, and it worked well for me.

Comment: @Tawani: Do you mind me asking why you're serializing it to JSON instead of just submitting it and figuring it out server side?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: The submitted to a REST web service that exists on another webserver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that what you'd do is this: for each input, first split the name at the separators (the '.' characters).  Now, you have an array of names. You can then iterate through that array, making sure that your target "assembly" object (and sub-objects) have containers every time you come across a new name segment. When the array has 1 element in it, you simply add the value.

```
$.fn.extractObject = function() {
  var accum = {};
  function add(accum, namev, value) {
    if (namev.length == 1)
      accum[namev[0]] = value;
    else {
      if (accum[namev[0]] == null)
        accum[namev[0]] = {};
      add(accum[namev[0]], namev.slice(1), value);
    }
  }; 
  this.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
    add(accum, $(this).attr('name').split('.'), $(this).val());
  });
  return accum;
});
// ...

var object = $('#myform').extractObject();
```

I just sort-of made that up so there might be a bug or two; I can't remember whether all the browsers have "slice" but I think they do.

(edit: I forgot the all-important call to `split()`)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I also added checks for buttons, multiple checkboxes (with same name) and elements without names.

Comment: quick'n dirty trick to handle checkbox input, to add just before "add(accum, $(this).attr(..."  :


`if( $(this).attr('checked') && ('checked' == $(this).attr('checked'))) {
    $(this).val(true);
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the form fields by name, use `String#split` to split the names on dot, and build up your resulting structure. Concept code:

```
function serializeDeep(form) {
    var rv, obj, elements, element, index, names, nameIndex, value;

    rv = {};
    elements = form.elements;
    for (index = 0; index < elements.length; ++index) {
        element = elements[index];
        name = element.name;
        if (name) {
            value = $(element).val();
            names = name.split(".");
            obj = rv;
            for (nameIndex = 0; nameIndex < names.length; ++nameIndex) {
                name = names[nameIndex];
                if (nameIndex == names.length - 1) {
                    obj[name] = value;
                }
                else {
                    obj = obj[name] = obj[name] || {};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Note that that doesn't allow for fields with repeated names (which should create arrays), nor does it elegantly handle a situation where you use the names "foo" and "foo.bar". But it should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed it this way:

```
$('#Myform').attr('onsubmit', 'test()');

function test() {

  var obj = {};

  obj.title =$('#title').prop('value');
  console.log('title: '+obj.title);

  obj.website =$('#website').prop('value');
  console.log('website: '+obj.website);

  obj.tags =$('#tags').prop('value').split(',');
  console.log('tags: '+obj.tags);

  do_something(JSON.stringify(obj));

}
```

Of course this can be done if you know what the names are, and I am in fact generating the table itself using Formation plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

### I created an example for this question by using plain js, please check developer tool console to see the data object!

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/seanyang414/3h3en8w2/1/)

```
var data = {};
var array = 'person.name.first'.split('.');
var value = 'myFirstName';
generateObj(data, array, value);
console.log(data);

function generateObj(obj, arr, val) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        obj[arr[0]] = val
        return;
    } 

    var restArr = arr.splice(1);
    if (!obj[arr[0]]) {
        obj[arr[0]] = {};
    }
    generateObj(obj[arr[0]], restArr, val);
}
```

#### solution:

1. transform each name string to array.
2. iterate through each array.
3. recursively call a method which create an obj and set this obj as the value of the property and pass this obj to the next recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Create an object of that shape then use a [JSON encoder](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to write it out.

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about.

Comment: *"What's your take then?"* How to do part 1 of your answer.

Comment: I just typed in an answer - he wants the dotted names to imply structure.