# Get value of JSON object with inner objects by HTML form field name without eval

Tags: javascript, json, object, eval, forms

I have a problem like this [Convert an HTML form field to a JSON object with inner objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552836/convert-an-html-form-field-to-a-json-object-with-inner-objects) but in to the other direction.

This is the JSON Object response from the server:

```
{
    company : "ACME, INC.",
    contact : {
        firstname : "Daffy", 
        lastname : "Duck"
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML form:

```
<form id="myform">
    Company: <input type="text" name="company" />
    First Name: <input type="text" name="contact.firstname" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="contact.lastname" />
</form>
```

And this is the (pseudo)code:

```
var aFormFields; 

for (var i = 0, iMax = aFormFields.length; i < iMax; i++) {

    var sFieldName = aFormFields[i].getAttribute('name');
    eval("sFieldValue = oResponse."+sFieldName);

}
```

Ok my solution works, but i looking for a good way to remove the evil eval from the code.
And the solution should also work for form fields with any count of dots in the field name.

Comment: Your instinct is correct: if you think you need to use `eval()`, then there's probably something new you need to learn about :-)  Keep sniffing your code!

Comment: I'm not quite sure: Do you want to fill the input fields from the AJAX server response, or do you want to generate the server response from the contents of the input fields?

Comment: On an unrelated note:  the response from the server is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for a single property:

```
sFieldValue = oResponse[sFieldName]
```

But it won't work for nested data like contact.firstname.
For that, split the name by dots, and use loop through each name:

```
var aFormFields; 

for (var i = 0, iMax = aFormFields.length; i < iMax; i++) {

    var aFieldNameParts = aFormFields[i].getAttribute('name').split(".");
    var oFieldValue = oResponse;
    for(var j=0; j<aFieldNameParts.length; j++) {
        oFieldValue = oFieldValue[aFieldNameParts[j]];
    }
    var sFieldValue = oFieldValue;
}
```

Note: if a property does not exist, an error will occur. You might want to check whether `oFieldValue[ aFieldNameParts[j] ]` exists or not.

Comment: thx, you made my day! this is the right solution i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
eval("sFieldValue = oResponse."+sFieldName);
```

Use for single dotted fields:

```
sFieldValue = oResponse[sFieldName];
```

This will retrieve the value via its key.

Now if you need more than that you need to do the following:

1. Split `sFieldName` on `.`
2. Loop over that array and go down in `oResponse` till you reach the value that you desire

Code could look like this:

```
var node = oResponse, parts = sFieldName.split('.');
while(parts.length > 0) {
   node = node[parts.shift()];
}
// node will now have the desired value
```

Further information on "Member Operators":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Comment: yes this works: sFieldValue = oResponse['company'];
but this doesn´t sFieldValue = oResponse['contact.firstname']

Comment: Sorry for that, didn't spot it my apologies, I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, I wouldn't loop over the input fields, but over the JSON object:

```
function fillForm (form, data, prefix) {
  prefix = prefix ? prefix + "." : "";
  for (var x in data) {
    if (typeof data[x] === "string") {
      var input = form.elements[prefix + x];
      if (input)
        input.value = data[x];
    } else
      fillForm(form, data[x], prefix + x);
  }
}

fillForm(document.getElementById("myform"), oResponse);
```

(untested)

Comment: this is a good idea, but not in my case because i have more elements in the json object the fields in html form. so i prefer to loop over the form fields

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your naming scheme is consistent, you can convert the dot-notation into subscripts.  You'd have to split the field name on the period and iterate or recurse over the tokens, converting each into a subscript.  Of course this assumes that `oResponse` always contains a value for every field.

```
for (var i = 0; i < aFormFields.length; i++) {
    var sFieldName = aFormFields[i].getAttribute('name');
    var tokens = sFieldName.split('.');
    var cur = oResponse;

    for (var j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
        cur = cur[tokens[j]];
    }

    sFieldValue = cur;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please treat this as a combination of answer and question :)

i am currently trying to get my server to jsonify the data that i get sent from a form just like you...

in my case the form will in the end create a json object with multiple subobjects that can have subobjects which can have... as well.

the depth is up to the user so i should be able to support infinite recursion.

my "solution" so far just feels wrong, but it correctly does the job,
the function getRequestBody gets fed a req.body object from expressjs,
this is basically an object with the following mapping:

```
{
  "ridic-ulously-deep-subobject": "value",
  "ridic-ulously-deep-subobject2": "value",
  "ridic-ulously-deep2-subobject3": "value",
}
```

the following html is in use:

```
<form>
    <input name="ridic-ulously-long-class-string" value="my value" />
  </form>
```

and the javascript function (that should work genericly, feed it a req.body object like above and it will return a json object):

```
function getRequestBody(reqB){

  var reqBody = {};

  for(var keys in reqB) {

    var keyArr = keys.split('-');

    switch(keyArr.length){
      case 1:
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]] = {};
        reqBody[keyArr[0]] = reqB[keys];
      break;

      case 2:
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]] = {};
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]] = {};

        reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]] = reqB[keys];
      break;

      case 3:
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]] = {};
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]] = {};
        if(!reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]][keyArr[2]]) reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]][keyArr[2]] = {};

        reqBody[keyArr[0]][keyArr[1]][keyArr[2]] = reqB[keys];
      break;

      case 4:

      // ...
      //and so on, always one line longer
  }

    return reqBody;
}
```

this just feels wrong and its only covering 5 levels of subobjects right now,
it might happen that an application has enough functionality to reach seven or even ten levels though.

this *should* be a common problem, but my search effort turned up nothing within 10 minutes,
which usually means that i am missing some keywords
or
that there is no viable solution [yet] (which i cant really imagine in this case).

is there someone out there who has imagination and logic sufficient enough to unspaghettify this or will i just have to expand this function with even more clutter to get me down to 10 possible sublevels?

i think that in the end it wont make a big difference performance wise, 
but i would really like NOT to create this awful behemoth :D

have fun

jascha